# How do I use PHP to query my SQL database using SELECT tag in html

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

Basically I'd like to use the choices which the user has selected from a different select tags, and in essence store these as variables which I can then use to query my database in SQL.

My HTML code is here:

```html
<div id ="search_elements">

    <img  src="UniSelect.jpeg">

    <select>
        <option selected disabled>Select a university</option>
        <option value="ucl">UCL</option>
        <option value="kings">Kings College</option>
        <option value="imperial">Imperial College</option>
        <option value="lse">London School of Economics</option>
    </select>

    <img  src="PriceSelect.jpeg">

    <select>
        <option selected disabled>Select a weekly rent price</option>
        <option value="50">0-£50</option>
        <option value="100"> £100-£150</option>
        <option value="150">£150-200</option>
        <option value="200"> £200+</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And the type of php i would be looking to use would be:

```php
//$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","adam","YjM3ZTYwOTQ5OWRmYWZh","adam_...");
//if (mysqli_connect_errno())
//  {
//     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
//  }

// Perform queries 
//$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT CONTENT FROM Blog WHERE ID = 01");
//$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

//echo $result['CONTENT'];
//mysqli_close($con);
```

To make it clear once more, I want to use the different values which the user selects, upon clicking a search button, have these query results shown in a table.

Comment: Hmm... you want values from university and rent price?

Comment: Yeah I want to store and use one value from each select element. So one for university and one for rent price

Comment: Are these selections in `<form>`?

Comment: Add name attribute for each select tag

Comment: In addition to the comments from Edvin about properly escaping data before use for SQL, you may wish to take a look at PDO - it's just as easy to use as mysqli - but offers the chance to connect to a plethora of different database engines. In one instance, I have precisely the same code running under MySQL, SQLite and SQLServer- the only thing that is different in the 3 installations is the connection string - a single line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution a little differs from yours because you have no provided your form, submit button, etc. but in general, after a few changes, it should work too:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <img src="UniSelect.jpeg">

    <select name="university">
        <option selected disabled>Select a university</option>
        <option value="ucl">UCL</option>
        <option value="kings">Kings College</option>
        <option value="imperial">Imperial College</option>
        <option value="lse">London School of Economics</option>
    </select>

    <img src="PriceSelect.jpeg">

    <select name="rent_price">
        <option selected disabled>Select a weekly rent price</option>
        <option value="50">0-£50</option>
        <option value="100"> £100-£150</option>
        <option value="150">£150-200</option>
        <option value="200"> £200+</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

And now, to get values of these (something like this and I recommend to place it above your form):

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // Checking connection in here

    $university_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['university']);
    $rent_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['rent_price']);

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM university WHERE name = '".$university_id."'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    // Same thing goes for rent price
}
```

Comment: would I not be able to use a format whereby I follow the syntax of a standard query, so " SELECT university FROM TABLENAME WHERE...."etc

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your comment. Can you explain more?

Comment: Do you mean this?: `SELECT university FROM tableName WHERE university = $_POST["university"]` (etc.)? But don't forget to escape variables.

Comment: Yes! Something like that, but how would it work in practice with correct syntax?

Comment: This is actually a correct syntax. Just to for escaping write before this query: `$_POST["university"] = $con->real_escape_string($_POST["university"]);` (actually, it's better to assign to a new variable, not overwrite, but for now let's leave as it is to avoid confusion. Better solution would be: `$university = $con->real_escape_string($_POST["university"]);` and then use `$university` in my written query).

Comment: Could you weave it into my php in the question so I'm clear on the final solution?

Comment: @AdamKona Done. You can check if it works now. Don't forget to mark answer as accepted if it solved your issue as it helps me a lot. Thanks!